# mysql event cannot call procedures to partition database

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

Have anyone faced the same problem as mine ? please kindly help !!

I have two procedures and one event, the procedures are working just fine when I call them separately from the command line.

But those procedures can not be called from inside the mysql event.
Below are my procedures, mysql event and how I check the effective result:

```
USE ims_db;
DELIMITER;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CreatePartition$$
CREATE PROCEDURE CreatePartition(day_keep_data INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE partition_temp TEXT;
    DECLARE partition_name CHAR(12);
    DECLARE partition_threshold INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE day_temp INT;
    SET day_temp = day_keep_data;

    SET @sql = concat('ALTER TABLE ims_db.ims_counter PARTITION BY RANGE(trigger_time)(');
    loop_change_partition: LOOP
        IF day_temp <= 0 THEN
            LEAVE loop_change_partition;
        END IF;

        SET day_temp = day_temp - 1;
        SET partition_threshold = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400*day_temp;
        SET partition_name = concat('p', CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL day_temp DAY + 0);
        SET partition_temp = concat('PARTITION', partition_name, ' VALUES LESS THAN (', partition_threshold,'), ');
        SET @sql = concat(@sql, partition_temp);
    END LOOP loop_change_partition;

    SET partition_name = concat('p', CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY + 0);
    SET partition_temp = concat('PARTITION', partition_name, ' VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE);');
    SET @sql = concat(@sql, partition_temp);
    prepare stmt from @sql;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;


DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DeleteOldData$$
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteOldData(day_keep_data INT)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = concat('DELETE FROM ims_db.ims_counter WHERE ims_db.ims_counter.id > 0
                                                      AND ims_db.ims_counter.trigger_time < ', UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400*day_keep_data);
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt;
        deallocate prepare stmt;
    ALTER TABLE ims_counter REMOVE PARTITIONING;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

-- DELIMITER $$
-- CREATE FUNCTION ims_daily_work() RETURNS INT(11)
-- BEGIN
--     CALL DeleteOldData(30);
--     CALL CreatePartition(30);
-- END $$
-- DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT IMSDailyWork
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 SECOND STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 10 SECOND
DO
BEGIN
    CALL DeleteOldData(30);
    CALL CreatePartition(30);
    -- SELECT ims_daily_work();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

How I check the effective result:

- run command: show table status like 'ims_counter'\G -> check `Create_options:` -> it is null
- after running all the above event and procedures -> check again `Create_options:` -> it should be 'partitioned', but my problem is there's no such 'partitioned' like that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: it is because my 'event_scheduler' is OFF, so no EVENT can be launched.

> 1. to check event status: show global variables like 'event_scheduler';
> 2. to enable event_scheduler: set global event_scheduler=1;